# Why do I get this error when installing VirtualBox Guest Additions on a macOS Mojave guest?

Tags: macos, virtualbox

VirtualBox version is `6.1.6`.

macOS Mojave version is `10.14.6`.

> **System Extension Blocked**
>
> A program tried to load one or more system extensions that are incompatible with this version of macOS. Please contact "Oracle America, Inc." for support.

[image: System Extension Blocked]

Running `tail -f /var/log/system.log` reveals an underlying issue with `org.virtualbox.additions.vboxservice` and `org.virtualbox.additions.vboxclient`.

[image: org.virtualbox.additions]

Comment: Update VBox, try again.

Comment: As a rule, I wouldn't install anything coming from the App Store. I'd rather visit the editor's website and download directly from there the .dmg install file AND the Guest Additions file associated to it by version number.

Comment: @Tetsujin Already done. Running latest.

Comment: @Didier I installed VirtualBox from a `.dmg` I downloaded directly from Oracle, not the app store.

Comment: a) You can't get VB on the App Store. b) Your question still says 6.0.2, current is 6.1.6

Comment: See this: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=95286

Comment: @Tetsujin You are right... not sure why auto-update didn't mention 6.1.6. Trying that now!

Comment: @Tetsujin Same issue on `6.1.6`.

Comment: @Tetsujin Is it possible that the KEXT supplied by Oracle in version `6.1.6` simply isn’t compatible with macOS Mojave `10.14.6`?